Logistic regression power analysis using two R packages differ
I am using prop.test in R to test binomial proportions and Hmisc::bpower to calculate its power.
For power of logistic regression Wald test I am using WebPower::wp.logistic (based on Demidenko, 2007).
I also simulated data to compare power. The code is included below. I was suprised by the discrepancies in results using the two approaches because they indicated that logistic regression would have more power.
I tried this for 2 population sizes (N=1E3 and 120E3), 3% or 10% being exposed (to some treatment for example) and incidence of a disease was 6% in unexposed persons and 7.2% or 15%  among exposed persons respectively.
The functions  Hmisc::bpower and WebPower::wp.logistic indicated that logistic regression would have better power. However, the simulation results consistently indicate that (at least for large sample sizes) there is hardly any difference or that prop.test is slightly more powerful.
Clearly Hmisc::bpower is closer to the simulation results and wp.logistic overestimates the power. I wonder why this happens? So, even if I plan to use logistic regression, should I use the power calculator Hmisc::bpower? This would only apply to a model with a single dichotomous predictor, for continuous predictor I assume I would need to use WebPower::wp.logistic and I am wondering if it would overestimate the power in that case as well.
##  Results comparing power of logistic regression vs test for proportions 
##  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
##  calculated using the code below
##   row: significance level: 0.05 or 0.01, 
##      group differences are set s.t. power at 0.05 will be around 0.8
##   columns:  
##   "binom(sim)" and "bpower" are powers for test of binomial proportions
##     using simulations (sim) or "bpower" given by Hmisc::bpower
##   "logistic(sim)" and  "wp.logistic" same for logistic regression
##     "wp.logistic" are results given by WebPower::wp.logistic
##
##   quantity listed is power of the test for equality of proportions 
##      in  the 2 groups. 
##     P1=0.06 and p2 are set s.t. power (at 0.05) is close to 0.8

#     bin_logistic_simu(n=120E3,p1=0.06,p2=0.072,exposed=0.03,nsim=2E4)
#
#           binom(sim) logistic(sim)      bpower    wp.logistic
#     p0.05     0.8246        0.8240      0.8263         0.8445
#     p0.01     0.6377        0.6368      0.6447         0.6544


#     > bin_logistic_simu(n=1E3,p1=0.06,p2=0.14,exposed=0.1,nsim=1E5)
#
#           binom(sim) logistic(sim)      bpower    wp.logistic
#     p0.05     0.7832        0.7777      0.7843         0.8317
#     p0.01     0.6262        0.6084      0.6283         0.6349



##  R-code
##  ------
##    bin_logistic_simu calculates power, compares simulations vs using
##    two R-packages, cal_pvals calculates p-values (for a simulated data)

library('simDAG')
library('WebPower')
library('Hmisc')

bin_logistic_simu<-function(n=1E4,p1=0.06,p2=0.08,exposed=0.03,nsim=1E4)
{ # generate data sets with z=1 being exposed, 0/1 outcome y
  # and probability p1 p2 in unexposed and exposed respectively
  #calculate p-values
res<-NULL

#p-values for simulated data sets:
for (i in 1:nsim) {
  n2<-trunc(exposed*n); n1<-n-n2
  y1<-simDAG::rbernoulli(n1,p1)
  y2<-simDAG::rbernoulli(n2,p2)
  y<-c(y1,y2); z<-c(rep(c(0,1),c(n1,n2)))
  dd<-data.frame(y,z)
  res<-rbind(res,cal_pvals(dd))
  }

# create table for results
 colnames(res)<-c('binom(sim)','logistic(sim)')
# from p-values calculate power at 0.05 and 0.01:
 res005<-sign(1+sign(0.05-res)) #power for p=0.05
 res001<-sign(1+sign(0.01-res)) #power for p=0.01
 pow<-rbind(apply(res005,2,mean),apply(res001,2,mean))
 rownames(pow)<-c('p0.05','p0.01')

#calculate corresponding power using formulas via two R packages
# binomial proportions test
binPow005<-Hmisc::bpower(p1=p1, p2=p2,  n1=n1, n2=n2, alpha=0.05)
binPow001<-Hmisc::bpower(p1=p1, p2=p2,  n1=n1, n2=n2, alpha=0.01)
# logistic regression (Wald) test
regPow005<-WebPower::wp.logistic(n=n, p0=p1, p1=p2, alpha=0.05, 
      power=NULL, alternative = "two.sided", family="Bernoulli", 
      parameter=exposed)$power
regPow001<-WebPower::wp.logistic(n=n, p0=p1, p1=p2, alpha=0.01, 
  power=NULL, alternative = "two.sided", family="Bernoulli", 
  parameter=exposed)$power
pow<-cbind(pow,c(binPow005,binPow001),c(regPow005,regPow001))
colnames(pow)<-c(colnames(pow)[c(1,2)],'binom(form)','logistic(form)')
round(pow,4)}

cal_pvals<-function(dd)
{#p-values for equality of proportions in 2 samples
 # p1=binomial proportions test,  p2=logistic regression

xx<-c(sum(dd$y[which(dd$z==0)]),sum(dd$y[which(dd$z==1)]))  
nn<-c(length(which(dd$z==0)),length(which(dd$z==1)))

p1<-prop.test(xx,nn,correct=F)$p.value
mm<-summary(glm(y~z,data=dd,family=binomial(lin='logit')))
p2<-mm$coefficients['z','Pr(>|z|)']

# p-values: p1 for binom proportions test and p2 for logistic regr
c(p1,p2)
}




As the two functions use different methods to estimate power, you shouldn't be surprised that they differ a bit. The bpower() function uses a close approximation to exact power calculations, while wp.logistic() is based, as you note, on the asymptotic normal approximation to the logistic-regression coefficient estimate (in log-odds scale) that underlies the Wald test. In very large samples those should become close to each other, although what constitutes "large" depends on details.
That said, the actual differences among your power estimates in any of your scenarios are pretty small, with the biggest discrepancies all less than 0.03.  In practice, I suspect that those discrepancies will be overwhelmed by the uncertainty in the other assumptions that you need to make.
As you seem comfortable in simulating data to estimate power, consider doing that instead of relying on the canned programs. That will force you to consider in detail the assumptions underlying your power estimates. Then maybe check against wp.logistic(). If you are planning on a multiple binomial regression, you probably will be relying on the default Wald tests reported in the model summary, anyway.
